# Create CSV file to the specific place on server in PHP with given HTML content

Tags: php, html, csv

I have created CSV file using following code.

```
<?php
    $orders = '<table><tr class="dataTableRow"><td><b>Order ID</b></td><td>Ordered By</td><td>Email</td><td>Ordered On</td><td>Completed On</td><td>Line Items</td><td>Order Total</td>></table>';
    $text = "PHP";
    $list = array (
    array('111', '222', '333'),
    array($text),
    array($orders)
    );

    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

All data in CSV is properly displayed except the HTML content. I want to format contents inside CSV. I need some text in bold and some in italic.

[image: Output of code]

Is there any other way or any solution for this? Please help if somebody knows.

Comment: CSV is TEXT only.

Comment: As my content is in German language, All the calculation which results float values are getting messy in MS excel in German. So I have tried CSV which is showing correctly all the calculation done in the file on both the MS Excel(German and English). That is why I jumped from XLS  to CSV. Now got stuck to format the content inside the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No chance, pal. CSV is plain text and you cannot format anything in plain text :-)

Comment: Ups. I didnt know this. **Thanks** for your guidance. I will find another way for this.